# xypic: how to create an arrow between two arrows that do not share a common target and/or source

Tags: xy-pic

I've created the following diagram by using invisible arrows, I wonder if there is another solution without using them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newdir{:=}{{}} %creates an empty shaft directional, the ":=" is chosen "randomly"
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{A\ar@/^{1pc}/[dd]^{a}="a"\ar@/_{1pc}/[dd]_{b}="b" & \ar@{:=}@/^{2.0pc}/[dd]^{{}}="a"\ar@{:=}@/_{3.8pc}/[dd]^{{}}="b"\ar@/^{1.5pc}/@{=>}^{X}"b";"a" & A'\ar@/^{1pc}/[dd]^{a'}="a"\ar@/_{1pc}/[dd]_{b'}="b"\\
\\
B &  & B'
}
\]
\end{document}
```

This gives the following diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply name the label of your existing arrows, and then draw an arrow between them.

Note that in your code is actually doing that, but then you create an invisible arrow that you rename with the same name (`"a"`). It's a bit strange.

Here is a solution :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@=1.5cm{
Fx\ar@{..>}[r]^{\eta(x)}
\ar@/^1pc/[d]^{Fg}="a" \ar@/_1pc/[d]_{Fg'}="c"
& \tilde Fx\ar@/^1pc/[d]^{\tilde Fg}="b" \ar@/_1pc/[d]_{\tilde Fg'}="d"\\
%
Fy \ar@{..>}[r]^{\eta(y)}& \tilde Fy
\ar@{=>}@/_1pc/"a";"b"
\ar@{=>}@/^1pc/"c";"d"
}
\]
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Note also that you can choose the size of the rows and column of your diagram with `\xymatrix@=<dimension>`. It's more elegant than doubling all the columns and rows.

Comment: Thank you again Matsaya, the point is that I did it before (giving to all arrows different names and linking them) but I don't know why it did not work...
Anyway, the point is that now the Fg -> F~g' arrow stops far from where I want it to stop (next to the F~x -> F~y), I tried to use "a"+<...,...>;"b"+<...,...> but it won't work!

Comment: @ubugnu, I see what you want to do, but it doesn't work for me neither, and I don't know another way to do it. Sorry. Notice that `"b"+< , >` works for straight arrows.

Comment: nevermind, I'll choose the invisible arrows solution, I can control more accurately positions of sources and targets, I thank you for your precious help